# how to realize countifs function (excel) in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset containing 100000 rows of data. I tried to do some `countif` operations in Excel, but it was prohibitively slow. So I am wondering if this kind of operation can be done in R? Basically, I want to do a count based on multiple conditions. For example, I can count on both occupation and sex

```
row sex occupation
  1   M    Student
  2   F    Analyst
  2   M    Analyst
```

Comment: What would be your required output? `table` or `aggregate` or a similar function is probably what you want.

Comment: you could use a pivot in Excel.

Answer (score 26):

Easy peasy. Your data frame will look like this:

```
df <- data.frame(sex=c('M','F','M'),
                 occupation=c('Student','Analyst','Analyst'))
```

You can then do the equivalent of a `COUNTIF` by first specifying the `IF` part, like so:

```
df$sex == 'M'
```

This will give you a boolean vector, i.e. a vector of `TRUE` and `FALSE`. What you want is to count the observations for which the condition is `TRUE`. Since in R `TRUE` and `FALSE` double as 1 and 0 you can simply `sum()` over the boolean vector. The equivalent of `COUNTIF(sex='M')` is therefore

```
sum(df$sex == 'M')
```

Should there be rows in which the `sex` is not specified the above will give back `NA`. In that case, if you just want to ignore the missing observations use

```
sum(df$sex == 'M', na.rm=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 8):

Here an example with 100000 rows (occupations are set here from  A to Z):

```
> a = data.frame(sex=sample(c("M", "F"), 100000, replace=T), occupation=sample(LETTERS, 100000, replace=T))
> sum(a$sex == "M" & a$occupation=="A")
[1] 1882
```

returns the number of males with occupation "A".

**EDIT**

As I understand from your comment, you want the counts of all possible combinations of sex and occupation. 
So first create a dataframe with all combinations:

```
combns = expand.grid(c("M", "F"), LETTERS)
```

and loop with `apply` to sum for your criteria and append the results to `combns`:

```
combns = cbind (combns, apply(combns, 1, function(x)sum(a$sex==x[1] & a$occupation==x[2])))
colnames(combns) = c("sex", "occupation", "count")
```

The first rows of your result look as follows:

```
  sex occupation count
1   M          A  1882
2   F          A  1869
3   M          B  1866
4   F          B  1904
5   M          C  1979
6   F          C  1910
```

Does this solve your problem?

**OR:**

Much easier solution suggested by thelatemai:

```
table(a$sex, a$occupation)


       A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I    J    K    L    M    N    O
  F 1869 1904 1910 1907 1894 1940 1964 1907 1918 1892 1962 1933 1886 1960 1972
  M 1882 1866 1979 1904 1895 1845 1946 1905 1999 1994 1933 1950 1876 1856 1911

       P    Q    R    S    T    U    V    W    X    Y    Z
  F 1908 1907 1883 1888 1943 1922 2016 1962 1885 1898 1889
  M 1928 1938 1916 1927 1972 1965 1946 1903 1965 1974 1906
```

Answer (score 1):

Given a dataset

```
df <- data.frame( sex = c('M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M'), 
                  occupation = c('analyst', 'dentist', 'dentist', 'analyst', 'cook') )
```

you can subset rows

```
df[df$sex == 'M',] # To get all males
df[df$occupation == 'analyst',] # All analysts
```

etc.

If you want to get number of rows, just call the function `nrow` such as

```
nrow(df[df$sex == 'M',])
```

Answer (score 1):

Table is the obvious choice, but it returns an object of class `table` which takes a few annoying steps to transform back into a `data.frame`
So, if you're OK using dplyr, you use the command `tally`:

```
    library(dplyr)
    df = data.frame(sex=sample(c("M", "F"), 100000, replace=T), occupation=sample(c('Analyst', 'Student'), 100000, replace=T)
    df %>% group_by_all() %>% tally()


# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   sex [2]
  sex   occupation `n()`
  <fct> <fct>      <int>
1 F     Analyst    25105
2 F     Student    24933
3 M     Analyst    24769
4 M     Student    25193
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(matrixStats)
> data <- rbind(c("M", "F", "M"), c("Student", "Analyst", "Analyst"))
> rowCounts(data, value = 'M') # output = 2 0
> rowCounts(data, value = 'F') # output = 1 0
```