# Elementary: COUNTIF on DataFrame using SUM function

Tags: r

After trying what was recommended previously for a similar challenge, I'm still lost and perhaps am missing something simple.

I have two data frames *Uniques* and *Uniques2*.

In *Uniques*, I have a column with 49,999 rows of a variable.

In *Uniques2*, I have separated out the unique variables and come up with a total of 403.

Now I would like to count how many time each variable in *Uniques2$aa.IndustryGroup* appears in a certain column in *Uniques$aa.IndustryGroup*. I would like it to display in a new column *$Count* in the *Uniques2* data frame.

A previous Stack [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23000661/how-to-realize-countifs-function-excel-in-r) recommended using == and SUM to find out the answer, which I thought was straightforward enough.

So I've tried this,

```
Uniques2$Count = data.frame(sum(Uniques$aa.IndustryGroup == Uniques2$aa.IndustryGroup))
```

And it returns errors about length which I know means that I'm not asking it to do what I want correctly.

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Count", value = list(sum.Uniques.aa.IndustryGroup....Uniques2.aa.IndustryGroup. = 138L)) : 
replacement has 1 row, data has 403
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In is.na(e1) | is.na(e2) :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In `==.default`(Uniques$aa.IndustryGroup, Uniques2$aa.IndustryGroup) :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Thanks for being a stellar community and leaving a trail of breadcrumbs. The success of this adventure would be improbable without you.

Comment: Please include a minimal example of your data set.

Comment: I think you somethink like `Uniques2$Count = lapply(Uniques2$aa.IndustryGroup,FUN=function(i)(sum(Uniques$aa.IndustryGroup == i)))`

Comment: You could probably use `ddply` and `summarize` on a larger data set summarizing by that variable of interest and doing a sum. Smth like: `ddply(Uniques, .(aa.IndustryGroup), summarize, val = length(aa.IndustryGroup))` ?

Comment: [How to make a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I would like to count how many time each variable in
>   Uniques2$aa.IndustryGroup appears in a certain column in
>   Uniques$aa.IndustryGroup. I would like it to display in a new column
>   $Count in the Uniques2 data frame.

```
# reproducible example!
set.seed(123)
Uniques <- data.frame(aa.IndustryGroup=sample(LETTERS,49999,replace=T))
Uniques2 <- data.frame(aa.IndustryGroup=LETTERS)

Uniques2$Count <- sapply(Uniques2$aa.IndustryGroup, 
                         function(x) sum(Uniques$aa.IndustryGroup==x))
```

*Explanation:* What you tried has two problems: first, you cannot store a `data.frame` in the vector `Uniques2$Count`.  Second, you cannot do vector comparison `v1 == v2` because as you know these vectors are of different lengths and you are really asking, for each element of `v2`, how many times does it appear in `v1`.  The `apply` family is a good way to do that.

Comment: This is the sample result: 

    aa.IndustryGroup....LETTERS Count
1                            A  1939
2                            B  1912
3                            C  1947

Problem being that I need to preserve the variables and I need to do a unique count where for some there are 5 and some there are 1,200. 

I do like your explanation of what I was screwing up, thanks for that, but the implemented code doesn't give the read I need.

Comment: Would you please edit your question to reflect what you mean by "preserve the variables"?  I believe I answered the question as written.  For example, 1939 is the number of times "A" appears in `Uniques$aa.IndustryGroup`.

Comment: Let's say one of the variables is Barbers, rather than having it change to a letter, I need it to continue to say Barbers since that is what it is looking for. 

When I run a similar check in Excel, I have 403 different values, with a range of 1 to 1782. When I run your example, I have 26 different values with a range of 1865 to 2017.

I may also have just not understood how to implement your code recommendation.

Comment: It would continue to say Barbers.  Since you did not provide example data sets, I created them.  In mine the industry groups are represented by the letters A-Z.  They are repeated in table 1, unique in table 2.  In yours it could be Barbers, Tailors, whatever.  You do not need to create my example data set.  You just need to use the `sapply` function as I wrote it for you but on *your* data set.  The example data set is just to show that it works.

Comment: > Uniques$Establishment_Count <- sapply(Uniques$aa.IndustryGroup, 
+                          function(x) sum(aa$IndustryGroup==x))
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Establishment_Count", value = list()) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 403

I think it may also be an issue that it is a data frame, and elsewhere I ran into trouble because it was a data frame and not a list. I've been reading about plyr, apply and sapply, watched the related videos from Coursera and still can't make this work.

Comment: There is at least one error in that, since `aa$IndustryGroup` needs a data.frame `aa` to work

Comment: This exists. Has 49,999 rows with 403 unique values.

Comment: You said your data.frames were called `Uniques` and `Uniques2`

Comment: Sorry, the data started with aa$IndustryGroup and then I used Uniques to create the 403, and removed Uniques2 entirely. Both Uniques and aa are data frames. Trying to simplify the steps to eliminate errors.

Comment: Check out @Batanichek 's answer above. I ended up getting that one to work.  Similar, if not almost identical. Thanks for your long winded perseverance.