# R - Excel countif over and under set values

Tags: r

I am wondering how I can perform this formula in R. It is counting over and equal to 400 and also counting under and equal to 400.

The formula is below for excel:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(B$2:$B$1048576,{"<=-400",">=400"},A$2:$A$1048576,"="&C2))
```

B2 column: Data 
A2 Column: Date 
C2 Column Matching Date

Here is an example date frame:

```
A (time series date)    B (data)    C (Numerical Date)
20140219              -412            20140219
20140219              -273.6666667    20140220
20140219              -228            20140221
20140219              -151.3333333    20140224
20140219              -157            20140225
20140219              -177.3333333    20140226
20140219              81.66666667     20140227
20140219              40              20140228
20140219              93.33333333     20140303
20140219              201.6666667     20140304
20140219              203.6666667     20140305
20140219              69              20140306
20140219              -22.66666667    20140307
20140219              49.33333333     20140310
20140219              40.33333333     20140311
20140219              194             20140312
20140219              74              20140313
20140219              333.3333333     20140314
20140219              283.6666667     20140317
20140219              176.6666667     20140318
20140219              219             20140319
20140219              276.6666667     20140320
20140219              107             20140321
20140219              138.3333333     20140324
```

As you can see... my time series date is in column A and this extends on a 1 minute basis all the way to present day. The data is in column b and column C is a helper column to aid pulling the data for that particular date, on matching date in that column... it then searches the data column for values over and under 400.

The goal here is to for each particular date, to count the numbers <=-400",">=400 for that given date. After its done one day, it then moves onto the next and populates the data frame with the results.

An example out put is below:

```
date    Count 400
20140819    25
20140820    50
20140821    46
20140822    48
20140825    43
20140826    17
20140827    18
20140828    18
20140829    44
20140902    57
```

In the sample data frame, the result would be total count 24 for date 20140219.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to realize countifs function (excel) in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23000661/how-to-realize-countifs-function-excel-in-r)

Comment: Why is it equal to 24 for your example dataframe? I can see only one value <= - 400, and none >= 400.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr`. Starting with example data:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(Date=c(rep("20170101",5), rep("20170102",5)),
                 Value=((runif(10)*1600)-800),
                 stringsAsFactors=F)

head(df)

       Date     Value
1  20170101 -375.1861
2  20170101 -204.6018
3  20170101  116.5654
4  20170101  653.1325
5  20170101 -477.3089
```

Use `abs(Value) >= 400` to find values that are `<=-400` or `>=400`, then `group_by` the `Date`, and count `n()`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   filter(abs(Value) >= 400) %>%
   group_by(Date) %>%
   summarise(Count=n())
```

Output:

```
      Date Count
1 20170101     2
2 20170102     3
```

Comment: Great solution, thank you! if i wanted to SUM, can this work in much the same way?

Comment: Yes, just replace `n()` with `sum(Value)`.

Answer (score 0):

Using base R I would do the following:

Chi's Fake Data (doing the heaven's work thank you):

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(rep("20170101", 5), rep("20170102", 5)),
                 B = ((runif(10) * 1600) - 800), stringsAsFactors = F)

df$D <- ifelse(abs(df$Value) >= 400, T, F) # Boolean column
sapply(split(df$D, df$Date), sum) # split and sum
# 20170101 20170102 
#        2        3
```

Or simply run the following function on your data:

```
# much larger data (2206800 rows)
df <- data.frame(Date = as.character(rep(20170101:20170713, each = 60*60)), Value =((runif(2206800)*1600)-800), stringsAsFactors=F)

sumcountif <- function(value, date, abs.cutoff) {
  m <- lapply(split(ifelse(abs(value) >= abs.cutoff, T, F), date), sum)
  d <- cbind.data.frame(date = names(m), unlist(m), stringsAsFactors = F)
  rownames(d) <- NULL
  colnames(d)[2] <- paste0("count_",substitute(abs.cutoff))
  d
}
sumcountif(df$Value, df$Date, 400) # inputs here
```