# How to compare two responses in R?

Tags: r, analysis

I'm analysing some data I collected in R, and I'm trying to see how many people gave a particular answer in one question and then a particular answer in another, i.e. the amount of people who answered both yes for Q1 and no for Q2. How would I go about doing this?

Edit:

I have two different columns in an excel file which I've exported as a csv file which I've imported into R.

Comment: The question as you posed it is difficult to answer, please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: can you give more details about your datasets ?

Comment: See the comment above by @Florian and how are 'yes' and 'no' coded?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying reproduce a countif or countifs in Excel, so the answer is at this post: [how to realize countifs function (excel) in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23000661/how-to-realize-countifs-function-excel-in-r)