# Is it possible to create a countif like function in R using ranges?

Tags: r, database, count

I've already read this question with an approach to counting entries in R:

[how to realize countifs function (excel) in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23000661/how-to-realize-countifs-function-excel-in-r)

I'm looking for a similar approach, except that I want to count data that is within a given range.

For example, let's say I have this dataset:

```
data <- data.frame( values = c(1,1.2,1.5,1.7,1.7,2))
```

Following the approach on the linked question, we would develop something like this:

```
count <- data$values == 1.5
sum(count)
```

Problem is, I want to be able to include in the count anything that varies 0.2 from 1.5 - that is, all possible number from 1.3 to 1.7.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 4):

```
sum(data$values>=1.3 & data$values<=1.7)
```

As the explanation in the question you linked to points out, when you just write out a boolean condition, it generates a vector of TRUEs and FALSEs the same length as your original dataframe. TRUE equals 1 and FALSE equals 0, so summing across it gives you a count. So it simply becomes a matter of putting your condition as a boolean phrase. In the case of more than one condition, you connect them with `&` or `|` (or) -- much the same way that you could do in excel (only in excel you have to do AND() or OR()).

(For a more general solution, you can use `dplyr::between` - it's also supposed to be faster since it's implemented in C++. In this case, it would be `sum(between(data$values,1.3,1.7)`.)

Answer (score 1):

Like @doviod writes, you can use a compound logical condition.
My approach is different, I wrote a function that takes the vector and as range the center point `value` and the distance `delta`.

After a suggestion by @doviod, I have set a default value `delta = 0`, so that if only `value` is passed, the function returns

> a count of cases where the values equal the value the user provides.
>   (doviod, in the comment)

```
countif <- function(x, value, delta = 0) 
  sum(value - delta <= x & x <= value + delta)

data <- data.frame( values = c(1,1.2,1.5,1.7,1.7,2))

countif(data$values, 1.5, 0.2)
#[1] 3
```

Comment: I would make delta default to 0 (`delta=0`), in which case if you only give the value, you get a count of cases where the values equal the value you provide.

Answer (score 1):

`which` identifies the location of all values in your vector that satisfy your criterion, and `length` subsequently counts the 'hits'.

```
length( which(data$values>=1.3 & data$values<=1.7) )
[1] 3
```

Comment: For some reason this approach isn't working properly. I have a vector with 814 observations, but this function returns more than 2k hits and I'm not even sure how this is possible. The way I'm implementing this logic is:
`cm <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(0,0,0,0), nrow = 2))`

`cm[1,1] <- length(which(subset(results, results$org>0 ) >= results$prev - mean(results$dist) & subset(results, results$org>0 ) <= results$prev + mean(results$dist)))`

Comment: Not sure. If class('your data') is a vector; this should work. Make sure it's not a factor. Perhaps you could update the answer with an example when it does not work. Then we could see what else it needs.